# Creating new columns based on row elements in python, have not found a pivot solution that works

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate, multiple-columns

I have a python dataframe that comes in as:

| Name | Up/Down | NumberA | NumberB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Up | 10.5 | +500 |
| John Smith | Down | 10.5 | -775 |
| Michael Johnson | Up | 7.5 | -200 |
| Michael Johnson | Down | 7.5 | -100 |

I'm trying to create a new table with new columns based on Up/Down:

| Name | NumberA | UpNumber | DownNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | 10.5 | +500 | -775 |
| Michael Johnson | 7.5 | -200 | -100 |

I've tried writing loops & using .merge but can't get exactly what I need (table above), please help!

Example:

```
for i in df['Up/Down']:
  if i contains 'Up':
    df['UpNumber'] = df['NumberB']
    else:
      df['DownNumber'] = df['NumberB']
```

^^This throws an invalid syntax error with "contains"

I have not found a pivot solution that works please don't remove question based on another's solution!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reshape your index and use `.unstack`

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Name','Up/Down','NumberA']
                  ).unstack(1).droplevel(0,1).add_suffix('Number')

print(df1)

Up/Down                  DownNumber  UpNumber
Name            NumberA
John Smith      10.5           -775       500
Michael Johnson 7.5            -100      -200
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this using a loop? The method you posted still creates 2 rows for each name in my actual table

Comment: @nbafan249 loops are discouraged using pandas you want to use the API to your advantage. Sounds like you need to use a `groupby`

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: I would read the documentation first: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html